# CSS Background-Image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup background images using CSS but I can't seem to get the images to populate correctly.

Here is the CSS for what I want to do

```
 a.fb {
   background-image: url('img/Facebook.png');
 }

 a.fb:hover {
  background-image: url('img/FacebookHover.png');
 }
```

Here is the html code that I am using, I have tried a couple of different ways to populate the images with no luck

```
<div class="footer">
     <a class="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Okay added the following and still not go any other thoughts

```
 a.fb {
    display:block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px
    background-image: url('img/Facebook.png');
 }
```

EDIT: Yup got it working now forgot the ; after height, but no I get a white border around it and tried setting border: none; no luck

```
a.fb {
    border: none;
    display:block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    background-image: url('img/Facebook.png');
 }
```

Comment: Are those images in correct path

Comment: Could be a few things. The path to your image may be wrong. Have you checked with the dev tools? Also your link has no content so unless you're styling it with CSS that's not posted here, it's essentially empty.

Comment: @Abu yes they are correct based on the site I am building

Comment: just add **;** after `height: 33px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also change the aproach completely and use html + mouseover and mouseout events:

```
<div class="footer">
    <a class="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"> 
        <img src="http://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="fb" name="fb" width="33px" height="33px" name="image_name" onmouseover="fb.src='http://goo.gl/cxiR7'; fb.width='38'; fb.height='38';" onmouseout="fb.src='http://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png'; fb.width='33'; fb.height='33';" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is a jsBin: http://jsbin.com/onehuw/1/edit

Answer (score 7):

An **anchor tag** by default shows as an inline elements, so it depends on its content in order to get a height and width. To do what you want, you should add some styles:  `display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px`.

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` only draws in the space that the element occupies. Your `a` tag has no content, and therefore it's width is 0. You'll not see any content (and background) until you give it at least some width (and height if needed).

Answer (score -3):

You need to add padding to the `<a>` tag otherwise it has a width and height of 0 for example:

```
a.fb {
  padding: 20px;
  background-image: url('img/Facebook.png');
}

a.fb:hover {
  background-image: url('img/FacebookHover.png');
}
```

You could also just set the width and height of the anchor

Comment: Sorry Hive7 but this is incorrect, padding is used to add some space between the element and the contents of the same element

Comment: No it expands the width of the `<a>`

Comment: it makes the box bigger because the padding adds space between the element border and the contents but is not used for set a width or height, for this, should be used width/height

Comment: No because as I said, is not correct. Should be used width/height

Comment: But here we are for learn and if we respond with something incorrect then people will think that is correct and will start to use a bad behavior

Comment: If it works then technically it is not incorrect, right. So what is your problem with it

Comment: This discussion does not make sense

Comment: spose though can you upvote me as its not really fair with all these downvotes when what I say isright